# PHP posting a dynamic array to SQL

Tags: php, sql, arrays, post, dynamic

Firstly, I apologise for my lack of knowledge, I am currently in education where a small portion of my coursework is web development. Apart from what I've already managed to self-teach, I have no knowledge of web design.

I am attempting to capture PHP variables that have been pulled an SQL database, while in a loop. I wish for these to be captured in an array, so that I can post the array back to the database. I know how to collect the variables in an array, but I do not know how to post an array back to SQL, where all the details in the array will be kept. For relevance, I currently know how to post variables to SQL, but not an array.

To put this in a specific context, I have an e-commerce website that has a cart page. This cart page will either be empty, or display one or more products (depending on what the user adds to the cart). The product details are collected from the SQL database. (This cart was given by a fellow student, who has explained that they've obtained it from another source, so I don't take credit or fully understand how the cart works.)

The reason for wanting to collect the products in the cart is so that when the user returns from a payment website (paypal in this example) that they are returned to a thank you page that will display what was purchase, along with where the hypothetical item would go (it's for an educational project, I don't aim to actually sell and send the products).

My understanding is that the cart runs through a while loop, nested in a foreach statement. I do not know how the cart knows which items have been added, and which haven't, I'm assuming this has to do with sessions. The while loop then prints the pulled variables, before continuing back to the start of the loop. I can add an array at the end of the loop (inside it), that would collect these variables.

My question is based on understanding how the array would collect the details of more than one product, and how would I post an array to the SQL database? Is there any way once these details have been collected to SQL to apply an auto increment ID for the collective order, not just singular items? (This way, I could call the whole order on the thank you page.)

Please find below the loop and any information from the cart that I believe to be of any relevance to it. I do not expect anyone to feed me answers, but if someone could explain generically how I would attempt this please. I hope that by showing what code I do have, that people know what kind of situation I am currently in.

I do apologise for this massive wall of text, but I wish to be as transparent as possible, so that hopefully people understand what I'm talking about, as I may wrongly explain stuff due to the lack of my own understanding.

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Jamie.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
    $cartOutput = "<h2 align='center'>Your shopping cart is empty</h2>";
} else {
    // Start PayPal Checkout Button
    $pp_checkout_btn .= '<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="ec1524964-facilitator@edinburghcollege.ac.uk">';
    // Start the For Each loop
    $i = 0; 
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
        $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE ISBN='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $title = $row["Title"];
            $value = $row["Value"];
            $description = $row["Description"];
        }
        $pricetotal = $value * $each_item['quantity'];
        $cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;
        setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "en_US");
        $pricetotal = money_format("%10.2n", $pricetotal);
        // Dynamic Checkout Btn Assembly
        $x = $i + 1;
        $pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name_' . $x . '" value="' . $title . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_' . $x . '" value="' . $value . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity_' . $x . '" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '">  ';
        // Create the product array variable
        $product_id_array .= "$item_id-".$each_item['quantity'].","; 
        // Dynamic table row assembly
        $cartOutput .= "<tr>";
        $cartOutput .= '<td><a href="product.php?ISBN=' . $item_id . '">' . $title . '</a><br /><img src="/admin_webpage/inventory_images/' . $item_id . '.jpg" alt="' . $title. '" width="40" height="52" border="1" /></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>' . $description . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>$' . $value . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post">
        <input name="quantity" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1" maxlength="2" />
        <input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="change" />
        <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
        </form></td>';
        //$cartOutput .= '<td>' . $each_item['quantity'] . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>' . $pricetotal . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post"><input name="deleteBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="X" /><input name="index_to_remove" type="hidden" value="' . $i . '" /></form></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '</tr>';
        $i++; 
    }
```

Comment: Your `mysql_` functions should be replaced/upgraded.  Your SELECT query is vulnerable to injection (research prepared statements, at least).  Your question has so much background/irrelevant information that I can't find the relevant information.  Please only provide the relevant input variables (the variables themselves and a raw sample of their possible values), your expected result using the input, and what steps you took to attempt to get your data from input to output.

Comment: Hey Mickmackusa, thank you for your feedback. I apologise for the non-specific data. I attempted not to be too generic, but as I don't have a solid foundation with PHP, I'm struggling to identify what exactly is important in this scenario, and which isn't. I appreciate the comment about SQL injection, however, as this will not be a live e-commerce website, as it's just for an educational project, I don't think I'll have to worry too much about that.
Thanks,
Jamie.